# Unhandled exception if call HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, exception, httpurlconnection

```
public  int coderesult (String urlstring) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(urlstring);
    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    //System.out.println("Response code is " + httpCon.getResponseCode());
    int mycode = httpCon.getResponseCode();
    return mycode;
}
public int displaycode () {
    int dispcode = 0;
    try {
        dispcode = coderesult(myurl);

    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
    }
    return dispcode;
}
```

Android Studio show errors in "dispcode = coderesult(myurl);" : "Unhandled exception:java.lang.Exception"

Comment: post full stacktrace and be specific. What did you get with this `httpCon.getResponseCode()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `codeResult()` method throws `Exception`

```
public  int coderesult (String urlstring) throws Exception {
```

Therefore, you must either catch it specifically `catch(Exception ex)` , or declare that your throw it from your method.

When catching exceptions, you either catch a specific exception type, or a more generic parent exception type. You could combine all catches into one catch, because all built in java exceptions extend from Exception

```
catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
public  int coderesult (String urlstring) throws IOException
```

and write

```
catch(IOException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @Andrey Andreev see the answer